# why does while loop using cin.get() function outputs result twice?

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int a ;
    while ( ( a = cin.get() ) != EOF )
    {

       cout << "hi" <<endl;

     } // end while


}
```

I wonder why this outputs "hi" twice whenever I input once.

for example

input : 1
output : hi 
         hi

Comment: Try: `echo -n "1" | ./a.out`

Comment: the output is number of chars + 1  times "hi"

Comment: @PavanChandaka: Why +1? Newline is a char too, part of the OP's input...and _that_'s the problem!

Comment: `while( cin >> a) cout << "Hi" << endl` if you want loop to stop while reaching EOF:  add inside loop `cin.sync();`

Comment: I mean the number of chars typed + 1. My bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input actually consists of *two* characters: the character `1` followed by a newline.

Try piping in the contents of a file that only contains one byte, or a one-letter string without newline, and you'll see only one `"hi"`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: No problem :-)

Comment: just select "enter" key with out entering any value. you will see a "hi". This explains your code takes a "newline" char.

Comment: Or turn off line buffering in your terminal emulator

Answer (score 1):

Add a line of code to print the value of `a`. That will help you understand what the input values the program sees:

```
int main()
{
    int a ;
    while ( ( a = cin.get() ) != EOF )
    {
       cout << a << endl;
       cout << "hi" << endl;    
    } // end while    
}
```

If your systems uses ASCII values for `char` encoding you can find out what the output means by looking up the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).